# Is there any way to sync map dragging in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use GMaps API v3 and I have two Google Maps standing side by side let's call the map to the left **X** and the map to the right **Y**. My question is if it's possible to make **Y** drag itself when user drags **X**?

I know how to detect the drag event on the google map, but how to apply the drag from one map to the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would try: In your drag event, use `getCenter()` on **X**, then use that lat-lng to `setCenter()` on **Y** . I am assuming you're using the map API's 'bounds_changed' event.

UPDATE: some thing like this:

```
//X and Y are map objects
google.maps.event.addListener(X, 'bounds_changed', (function () {
    Y.setCenter(X.getCenter());
}));
```

You can even add some logic using `setTimeout` to detect when the user stops dragging X, and only then set the center on Y.

Comment: Can you show an example how to use it correctly? I'm not really into GMapping actually ))

Comment: You're f****ng genius! Works like a charm. You just need to remove the brackets after the `function(){ ... }` **()** `))`. I've tried to edit it but SO says I need to edit at least 6 characters to submit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a similar functionality but required the zoom to also be mirrored.

As you might expect, it is very similar to the accepted answer:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', (function () {
    map2.setCenter(map.getCenter());
    map2.setZoom(map.getZoom());
}));
```

And here is a JSFiddle which demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/LREfU/